# Environment variables with double asterisks in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have noticed that in some Dockerfile the environment variables are specified using particular expressions, that perform some sort of variable substitution, such as:

```
ENV PASSWORD **Random**
ENV NAME **False**
```

I cannot find any reference to those expression in the Docker official documentation.

Where I can find a list of possible expressions that can be used in a Dockerfile and what is their meaning?

Comment: Do you have an example? A link to Docker hub with such a Dockerfile?

Comment: Take a look at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tutum/mysql/dockerfile/ for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's non-official convention to use these variables as template variables. They will be replaced in run-time.

Or you can replace them using `-e` switch of `docker run`.

For example:

```
ENV MYSQL_USER admin
ENV MYSQL_PASS **Random**

# Replication ENV
ENV REPLICATION_MASTER **False**
ENV REPLICATION_SLAVE **False**
```

If you take a look on start script you can see the following:

```
if [ "$MYSQL_PASS" = "**Random**" ]; then
    unset MYSQL_PASS
fi

PASS=${MYSQL_PASS:-$(pwgen -s 12 1)}
```

If variable value is `**Random**` let's replace it with a randomly generated password.